# Cross sections in Geant4

Tags: computational-physics, simulations, software, scattering-cross-section

Does anyone know where I can find the information about cross sections in Geant4? I would like to use my own file with cross section (exported from another code to MC simulations), but I cannot find the place where files with cross-sections are stored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a particular program which should be asked on [its user forum](http://hypernews.slac.stanford.edu/HyperNews/geant4/cindex)

Answer (score 0):

In GEANT most of the cross sections are programmed, i.e. they are realized by MC-code. First, in most cases differential cross section are used and their dependence of for instance energy and emission angle are realized by programming code. The formulas on these parameters can be found in the literature on nuclear physics, interaction of radiation with matter and high-energy physics. So in general it is not possible to change them by "connecting" a file with GEANT in order to control them by a file. The cross sections are, so to say, hard-wired implemented in GEANT.  But may be in the meantime (I used GEANT 20 years ago) there are some possibility to change a part of them as an additional tool available for the user, however, I guess, the most of the basic stuff is still hard-wired implemented.